# Why Jquery-AJAX Login requires "return false;"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.mostlikers.com/2015/05/ajax-login-system-in-codeigniter.html) on creating an AJAX based login. Given below, the relevant AJAX code :

```
$(".-submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if(data==0)
                window.location.href = "member";
            else
                $(".error_text").show();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This code is placed within `$(document).ready()` in the `<head>`. My question is: Why is the `return false;` necessary? Without it, the page does get refreshed whether or not the username/password is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for `return false` is equivalent to:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Which prevents the default action of the form being submitted traditionally and not by AJAX. By the time you click the submit button, using AJAX, JavaScript sends a request to the server and the whole process is done using JavaScript not a traditional form submission. The traditional form submission is synchronous, contrary to what you are performing, AJAX is asynchronous.

> *Without it, the page does gets refreshed*

Nopes, it submits the form after sending the request to the server. That would be a duplicate submission. Hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: So, the form gets submitted twice? Once via AJAX and once via traditional method?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Yes, so for preventing that to happen, we use either `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`.